# getElementsByName reports an error for a non existing form element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<FORM NAME="form1" METHOD="POST" ACTION="survey.php">
    <P>q1: How do you rate Ahmed Ebaid?</P>
    <P>
        <INPUT TYPE='Radio' Name='q1' value='1' id='q1'>1</P>
    <P>
        <INPUT TYPE='Radio' Name='q1' value='2' id='q1'>2</P>
    <P>
        <INPUT TYPE='Radio' Name='q1' value='3' id='q1'>3</P>
    <P>
        <INPUT TYPE='Radio' Name='q1' value='4' id='q1'>4</P>
    <P>
        <INPUT TYPE='Radio' Name='q1' value='5' id='q1'>5</P><span style='color:red' id='radio_error'></span>
    <p>q2: Who is your best best friend?</P>
    <select name='q21' id='q2'>
        <option value='0'>Select a Name</option>
        <option value='2001'>abc</option>
        <option value='2002'>def</option>
        <option value='2003'>ghi</option>
        <option value='2005'>jkl</option>
        <option value='2006'>mno</option>
        <option value='2007'>pqr</option>
        <option value='2008'>stu</option>
    </select>
    <select name='q22' id='q2'>
        <option value='0'>Select a Name</option>
        <option value='2001'>abc</option>
        <option value='2002'>def</option>
        <option value='2003'>ghi</option>
        <option value='2005'>jkl</option>
        <option value='2006'>mno</option>
        <option value='2007'>pqr</option>
        <option value='2008'>stu</option>
    </select>
    <select name='q23' id='q2'>
        <option value='0'>Select a Name</option>
        <option value='2001'>abc</option>
        <option value='2002'>def</option>
        <option value='2003'>ghi</option>
        <option value='2005'>jkl</option>
        <option value='2006'>mno</option>
        <option value='2007'>pqr</option>
        <option value='2008'>stu</option>
    </select>
    <P>q3: How do you rate def?</P>
    <P>
        <INPUT TYPE='Radio' Name='q3' value='1' id='q3'>1</P>
    <P>
        <INPUT TYPE='Radio' Name='q3' value='2' id='q3'>2</P>
    <P>
        <INPUT TYPE='Radio' Name='q3' value='3' id='q3'>3</P>
    <P>
        <INPUT TYPE='Radio' Name='q3' value='4' id='q3'>4</P>
    <P>
        <INPUT TYPE='Radio' Name='q3' value='5' id='q3'>5</P><span style='color:red' id='radio_error'></span>
    <p>q4: Who is your best best friend?</P>
    <select name='q41' id='q4'>
        <option value='0'>Select a Name</option>
        <option value='2001'>abc</option>
        <option value='2002'>def</option>
        <option value='2003'>ghi</option>
        <option value='2005'>jkl</option>
        <option value='2006'>mno</option>
        <option value='2007'>pqr</option>
        <option value='2008'>stu</option>
    </select>
    <select name='q42' id='q4'>
        <option value='0'>Select a Name</option>
        <option value='2001'>abc</option>
        <option value='2002'>def</option>
        <option value='2003'>ghi</option>
        <option value='2005'>jkl</option>
        <option value='2006'>mno</option>
        <option value='2007'>pqr</option>
        <option value='2008'>stu</option>
    </select>
    <select name='q43' id='q4'>
        <option value='0'>Select a Name</option>
        <option value='2001'>abc</option>
        <option value='2002'>def</option>
        <option value='2003'>ghi</option>
        <option value='2005'>jkl</option>
        <option value='2006'>mno</option>
        <option value='2007'>pqr</option>
        <option value='2008'>stu</option>
    </select>
    <select name='q44' id='q4'>
        <option value='0'>Select a Name</option>
        <option value='2001'>abc</option>
        <option value='2002'>def</option>
        <option value='2003'>ghi</option>
        <option value='2005'>jkl</option>
        <option value='2006'>mno</option>
        <option value='2007'>pqr</option>
        <option value='2008'>stu</option>
    </select>
    <P>q5: How do you rate the attitude of Farida Ebaid?</P>
    <P>
        <INPUT TYPE='Radio' Name='q5' value='1' id='q5'>1</P>
    <P>
        <INPUT TYPE='Radio' Name='q5' value='2' id='q5'>2</P>
    <P>
        <INPUT TYPE='Radio' Name='q5' value='3' id='q5'>3</P>
    <P></P>
    <P></P><span style='color:red' id='radio_error'></span>
    <p>
        <INPUT TYPE='hidden' Name='h2' VALUE=''>
    </P>
    <p>
        <INPUT TYPE="Submit" Name="Submit1" VALUE="Click here to vote">
    </P>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
                $('form').submit(function(e){
                    var answers = '';
            var len = 5;
                    $('input[type=Radio]:checked').each(function() {
                        if (answers !== '') {
                            answers += ',';
                        }
                        answers += $(this).val();
                //alert(answers);
                    })
                    $('input[name=h2]').val(answers);       
            for (var i = 1; i <= len; i++ ) {
                var qNum = 'q'+i;
                //document.write(qNum);
                if ($('#'+qNum+'').is(':radio')) {
                    if (($('input[name='+qNum+']:checked').length == 0) ){
                        alert("No Selection is made for "+ qNum);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else if ($('#'+qNum+'').is('select')) {
                    var j = 1;
                    var nominatefriend = qNum+j;
                    alert (nominatefriend);
                    var check = '';
                    var chosen = new Array();
                    while (check = document.getElementsByName("nominatefriend")) {
                        alert(check);
                        var len = document.form1[nominatefriend].length;
                        alert (len);
                        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                            if (document.form1[nominatefriend][i].selected) {
                                chosen[j] = document.form1[nominatefriend][i].value;
                                alert (chosen[j]);
                            }
                        }
                        j++;
                        nominatefriend = qNum+j;
                        alert (nominatefriend);
                    }
                }
            }   // for loop        
                }); // form submit function
        })//function
```

The above code executes fine. However, for q24 which is a non existing form element, it reports the following error. TypeError: document.form1[nominatefriend] is undefined. This is again a non existing form element. I'm thinking that the while loop should exit once a given form element doesn't exist.

Comment: A little off-topic, but you should never have multiple ID's on the same page.

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall.. **off-topic ??** . That is a good point to bring about

Comment: Ok, so this is a survey, and I'm creating multiple comboboxes for the same question. This comboboxes are the same. Is this still a problem.

Comment: Why is your HTML indented like that? Do you realize that it's invalid to have a `<p>` inside of another `<p>`?

Comment: @CrazyTrain, thanks for the tip. You are def. right.

Comment: Ahmed, have you looked at my fiddle below?  I changed my answer, and I reworked your code to be all JQuery based, using CSS Classes and properly using IDs for single objects.

Comment: @SeanKendle, thanks a lot for your help. I think I got your message late. However, I did a reformat for the whole code and I instead used JQuery, and I've avoided all duplicated IDs. I don't know if I should show my edits in this post or not.

Answer (score 1):

---

Ok, I've reworked this to use JQuery to look at each element rather than trying to find the names of each element using a loop.  I feel this is a more concise way to do it.

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanKendle/9VHF3/

```
check out the fiddle answer... let me know if you need more help.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work either. The main problem is that the initial variable for check used before had a value for q24 which is [object nodelist]

Comment: in chrome's javascript console, the following code shows the alertbox. `if (check = document.getElementsByName("nominatefriend")) alert('= something');` if I just run `(check = document.getElementsByName("nominatefriend"))`, then the result is `[]`. I'd be inclined to check that the .length member of the result of `getElementsByName` wasn't 0 - you may have to do that after checking to see that it's not `undefined`

Comment: @enhzflep, thanks a lot for your respond back. However, I modified this code and used JQuery instead as it took me a long time to figure how I can fix this.

Comment: Ahmed, since you sort of took my advice, even though you didn't use my code specifically, could you please accept this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around `nominateFriend`

```
while (check = document.getElementsByName(nominatefriend)) {
```

Also, I would suggest removing the assignment as well

```
while (document.getElementsByName(nominatefriend)) {
```